# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to log in in Angular app

Tags: angular, slim-3

I'm trying to set up an Angular app on my computer to continue the development. The front-end is made in Angular 7.1.4 and for the back-end Slim-3 is being used.

I have set everything up and on the `ng serve` the app compiles without any errors. The first screen is the login and when I try to log in I get this error in the console:

```
POST http://localhost:8888/api/auth net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

My app is running on localhost:4200, the URL for api is `http://localhost:8888/api/` this is set in the enviroments.ts file and in my proxy.conf.json file I have this code:

```
{
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8887",
      "secure": false
    }
}
```

I am also using MAMP...

EDIT: I have also tries setting all the ports to 4200 but it also didn't work

What am I doing wrong that I cant login in the app?

Comment: your conf.json is showing 8887 as port !

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I have tried changing it to 8888 and I keep getting the smae error

Comment: how are you starting the backend[slim api], are you starting using php webserver command, then use the same port number.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I am using gulp to start the backend api